# Converting only some object values into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

so I have this array of objects:

```
 [
    {
    "id": "774944",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774944",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
      "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
      }
    }
    },
    {
    "id": "774945",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774945",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
      "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
      }
    }
    },
    {
    "id": "774946",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774946",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
      "description": "<p><b>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
      }
    }
    },]
```

and I wish to extract all 'id' values from ii and insert them into array. I have managed to develop this:

```
let id_array = [];
class URLextracted extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: {},
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch({ShowResults()})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
}
render() {
const { id } = this.state.output;
id_array.push(id);
return id_array;
}
}
```

ShowResults() inserts an API link to the fetch above.
I'm not even sure if I should use a component here. I wish this to output this:

```
id_array = ['774944','774945','774946']
```

Can not figure out how to this by myself :/

Comment: `id_array = this.state.output.map(({id}) => id)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let id_array = [];
let myJSON = [{
    "id": "774944",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774944",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
      "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "774945",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774945",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
      "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "774946",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774946",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
      "description": "<p><b>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
];

myJSON.map(a => id_array.push(a.id));

console.log(id_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your data, extract the `id` and render this data if this is what you want here. I'm providing a working example. Do not think about the `getData` part. I'm just mimicking the fetch part here. You can examine the `render` part of the component. Also, I've changed the `output` state to an array since your data is actually an array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "774944",
    general: {
      presentable_id: "774944",
      name: "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
      description:
        "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    brand: {
      name: "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    images: {
      primary: {
        large: "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "774945",
    general: {
      presentable_id: "774945",
      name: "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
      description:
        "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    brand: {
      name: "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    images: {
      primary: {
        large: "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "774946",
    general: {
      presentable_id: "774946",
      name: "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
      description:
        "<p><b>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    brand: {
      name: "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    images: {
      primary: {
        large: "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
];

const getData = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 2000));

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    output: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getData().then(output => this.setState({ output }));
  }

  render() {
    const { output } = this.state;
    return !output.length ? (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    ) : (
      output.map(({ id }) => <div key={id}>{id}</div>)
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data  =  [
    {
    "id": "774944",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774944",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
      "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
      }
    }
    },
    {
    "id": "774945",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774945",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
      "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
      }
    }
    },
    {
    "id": "774946",
    "general": {
      "presentable_id": "774946",
      "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
      "description": "<p><b>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
    },
    "brand": {
      "name": "Brother Norge AS"
    },
    "images": {
      "primary": {
        "large": "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
      }
    }
    },]
    
    const result = data.map(res=>res.id);
    console.log(result)
```